# How to access StepExecution in partitioned CompositeItemProcessor

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a case where I want to access `StepExecution` from inside a `Processor` which is part of a `CompositeItemProcessor` which is part of a `partitioned step`.

I am able to access the `StepExecution` in the **very first partition** but am unable to access it in the subsequent partitions.

Here is my code:

Job:

```
@Bean("pendingPaymentAggregatorJob")
    public Job pendingPaymentAggregatorJob(Step populatePendingPaymentAggregatorCache,
                                           Step calculatePaymentRunPeriods,
                                           Step truncatePaymentPendingTables,
                                           Step fetchMaxPaymentId,
                                           Flow pendingPaymentsGenerationFlowForCompleteMonth,
                                           Step populatePendingTablesSecondHalfOfMonth) {
return jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB")
                .start(populatePendingPaymentAggregatorCache)
                .next(calculatePaymentRunPeriods)
                .next(truncatePaymentPendingTables)
                .next(fetchMaxPaymentId)
                .next(currentPeriodFlowDecider())
                .on(FIRST_HALF_OF_MONTH).to(pendingPaymentsGenerationFlowForCompleteMonth)
                .from(currentPeriodFlowDecider())
                .on(SECOND_HALF_OF_MONTH).to(populatePendingTablesSecondHalfOfMonth)
                .end()
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobExecutionListener)
                .build();
}
```

PartitionedStep:

```
var workerStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("NAME-worker")
           .<T, W>chunk(chunkSize)
           .reader(itemReader())
           .writer(itemWriter())
           .processor(compositeItemProcessor)
           .faultTolerant()
           .retryLimit(3)
           .retry(Exception.class)
           .listener(stepExecutionListener)
           .build();

SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(maxConcurrency);

return stepBuilderFactory.get("NAME")
          .partitioner(workerStep.getName(), partitioner())
          .step(workerStep)
          .gridSize(GRID_SIZE)
          .taskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor)
          .build();
```

CompositeItemProcessor:

```
@Bean
    public CompositeItemProcessor<PendingPayment, PaymentPendingEnvelop> compositeItemProcessor(
            PendingTaxDetailsProcessor pendingTaxDetailsProcessor,
            VatCalculatorProcessor vatCalculatorProcessor) throws Exception {

        CompositeItemProcessor<PendingPayment, PaymentPendingEnvelop> compositeItemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
        compositeItemProcessor.setDelegates(List.of(
                pendingTaxDetailsProcessor,
                vatCalculatorProcessor,
                (ItemProcessor<PendingPaymentsProcessorEnvelope, PaymentPendingEnvelop>) processorEnvelope -> PaymentPendingEnvelop.builder()
                        .paymentPendingTaxDetails(processorEnvelope.getPaymentPendingTaxDetails())
                        .build()
        ));
        compositeItemProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();

        return compositeItemProcessor;
    }
```

Processor:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Component
@StepScope
public class PendingTaxDetailsProcessor implements ItemProcessor<PendingPayment, PendingPaymentsProcessorEnvelope> {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Autowired
    public PendingTaxDetailsProcessor(@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public PendingPaymentsProcessorEnvelope process(PendingPayment pendingPayment) throws Exception {
        // Code

        int maxPaymentId = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getInt("maxPaymentId");
        if (maxPaymentId == 0) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Unable to get PaymentId from ExecutionContext");
        }
        int paymentId = maxPaymentId + 1;
        stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("maxPaymentId", paymentId);

        // Code

    }
}
```

I am able to access the context in the first partition which encounters this step but when the 2nd partition tries to do it, I get an exception.
In the below logs, you can see the first partition reading and writing successfully, but the 2nd partition throwing exception

```
2022-01-18 13:56:31.165  INFO 10193 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] c.a.b.l.CommonStepExecutionListener      : Step: POPULATE_PAYMENT_PENDING_TABLES_STEP-Period_1-worker:partition_1_2, Completion time: 2022-01-18T13:56:31.164932, Time taken: 2.153457343 secs, Read count: 1, Write count: 1, Status: COMPLETED
2022-01-18 13:56:33.583  INFO 10193 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] c.a.b.l.CommonStepExecutionListener      : Step: POPULATE_PAYMENT_PENDING_TABLES_STEP-Period_1-worker:partition_2_2 started at: 2022-01-18T13:56:33.583653
2022-01-18 13:56:33.900 ERROR 10193 --- [cTaskExecutor-6] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step POPULATE_PAYMENT_PENDING_TABLES_STEP-Period_1-worker in job PENDING_PAYMENTS_AGGREGATOR_JOB

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.pendingTaxDetailsProcessor' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/billing-paymentrun-service/target/classes/com/awin/billing/steps/pendingpaymentaggregator/processor/PendingTaxDetailsProcessor.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:676)
    at com.awin.billing.steps.pendingpaymentaggregator.processor.PendingTaxDetailsProcessor$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c5e2a24.process(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.processItem(CompositeItemProcessor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor.process(CompositeItemProcessor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$1.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.transform(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after some hits and tries with different approaches, I made it work.

The step fails in Bean creation of the `StepContext` object after the first partition. But when we do field injection instead of constructor injection, it works perfectly.

So instead of the injecting StepContext through Constructor,

```
@Autowired
public PendingTaxDetailsProcessor(@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}
```

we can do Field injection

```
@Value("#{stepExecution}")
private StepExecution stepExecution;
```

I don't know why is that the case (might be a bug), but this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

There's actually a few problems here.

1. You need to remove the @Configuration annotation as this is a Component and not a configuration class.
2. Since you are injecting the StepExecution through the constructor (which should work), you should not need the @BeforeStep method at all.
3. It looks like you are only a single value from the ExecutionContext and it probably makes sense to only inject that value

```
@Autowired
public PendingTaxDetailsProcessor(@Value("#{stepExecution['maxPaymentId'}") Integer maxPaymentId) {
    this.maxPaymentId = maxPaymentId;
}
```

4. Since you are updating the value you are retrieving, it should probably be in the StepContext instead of the JobContext and then promoted to the JobContext through a StepExecutionListener.
5. Also since you are updating the value, an Integer value won't work since it's immutable. Might want to look at wrapping it in an object that can be updated and then you won't need to put the value back in the ExecutionContext after updating it

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
1. Yes, you're right. 
2. I was trying out different things to make it work. Forgot to remove it while posting. I've edited the question now.
3. I need to update the value in the context as well. So need to get the context as well

Comment: 4. There is a whole chain before this step. The value is injected into jobContext by a tasklet.

5. I don't understand this. Integer is inserted into a ConcurrentHashMap inside the context. It should work in any case.

Comment: Ok I think I misread this question. You definitely want to always favor Constructor injection over Field injection mainly because it just makes it a lot easier for testing. I think you might also want to annotate your CompositeItemProcessor bean with @StepScope as well.  That might be the issue.

Comment: The processor already has an @StepScope annotation.

Comment: The CompositeItemProcessor bean, not the PendingTaxDetailsProcessor component